# Chart in Window phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hello,

I have used chart control in my application. I have bound Date  as IndependentValueBinding (X Axis). All code is working fine but date is display horizontal So if I have many value I dont find the perfect value related to date as there are many date in X axis. So How can I display Date as Vertical on X axis.

```
  <chart:BarSeries
                    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Date}"
                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Price}"/>
               <chart:Chart.LegendStyle>
                <Style TargetType="datavisual:Legend">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>

                </Style>
            </chart:Chart.LegendStyle>
        </chart:Chart>
```

Thanks,
Hitesh

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the style for AxisLabelStyle, I think WP version of charts should be the same as Silverlight:
[How to: Easily rotate the axis labels of a Silverlight/WPF Toolkit chart](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/03/06/turn-your-head-and-check-out-this-post-how-to-easily-rotate-the-axis-labels-of-a-silverlight-wpf-toolkit-chart.aspx)

Comment: I already tried this but I could not find System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit. So it gave me error.

Comment: You can use this implementation of layout transformer for Windows Phone http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/08/26/your-phone-can-turn-into-a-robot-layouttransformer-works-great-on-the-windows-phone-platform.aspx

Comment: I want for chart control and in example it gives for ListBox. I tried but i dont know how to use for chart control.it is not working for me.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on why it does not work for you? Do you see build breaks or it just does not do what it suppose to do?